# rmarkdown print html tag from data

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I would like to print (chunk) html links using the cat() function in a rmarkdown html document. Say I have 100 urls in a data frame and I want to make them clickable when I print them, at the moment knitr doesn't interpret the `<a>` tag

```
cat('<a href=', url, '> link</a>')
```

Comment: add `echo=FALSE` and `results="asis"` to your chunk options

Answer (score 0):

An alternative option to the chunk option `results='asis'` is to use the `htmltools` tags, which will print properly to HTML without changing the chunk options. For instance, install the `htmltools` package and then:

````
```{r}
url = 'https://google.com'
htmltools::tags$a("Click this link", href=url)
```
````

If you want to print the *data.frame* itself and have the links clickable, then
you can use e.g. the knitr::kable function. URLs will automatically get converted to links by pandoc when you render them:

````
```{r}
data(sleep)
sleep$url = 'https://google.com'
knitr::kable(sleep)
```
````

For a lot of links, you can do this in a more compact way with the DT package but you need "escape=FALSE" to get it to not mess up the HTML:

````
```{r}
data(sleep)
sleep$url = paste0('<a href="',url,'">Click here</a>')
DT::datatable(sleep, escape=FALSE)
```
````